# Is it possible to update HTML/CSS/JS files in a PhoneGap app with out re-deploying?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, phonegap-build

If a user has installed my PhoneGap app is there any way to update the static files such as the HTML or CSS with out the need to re-deploy the app again?
For example, when updating a web app, the developer can make a change to a CSS file on the server, and on the next page refresh the style change will be visible to the user.

I'm assuming being able to do this is unlikely due to the app needing to be packaged up and installed on the device, but I'm looking for some verification.

Comment: One idea is to import external CSS resources in your CSS file using `@import`. Did you try that? For eg., `@import url("http://example.com/latest/style.css");`

Comment: you can use content sync plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-contentsync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the app to import the file externally from a server (something like `<link rel="https://linktofile.com/file.css">`, which means you can change the app's style at any time without re-compiling the app.

Otherwise I am not aware of any other way.

Comment: Good idea for CSS, I don't think it would work quite the same for javascript though.

Comment: Agreed. This could result in weird bugs. Never tried a solution for what you need.

Comment: It looks like phone gap build offers a tool called Hydration that allows you to update the app with out the user necessarily having to re-install it.

Comment: That tool only works for development. If you have already compiled the app to binary and delivered it to the phone, you have to recompile it.

Comment: I want to add, if this is not clear, if the network goes down (or the route to the server) your App will visually break. This is one of the reasons it is not consider "best practice".

Comment: Agreed. You could also use a local css file as a fallback in the case the remote css file does not load (using a JS event listener for a timeout) but what a mess that could be.

Comment: That is a very valid point as well. So it sounds like there really is no way to iterate on the UX of a released app with out doing a full deployment.

Answer (score 0):

@Stavros_S
delopying a website as is suggested by Praveen Kumar is NOT best practice for mobile Apps.

Recently, Google created a new means to do what you want. It is called an *Expansion File*. Read this:

https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/adding-an-android-apk-expansion-file-to-a-cordova-project/

Comment: Unfortunately this only seems to be valid for Android apps.

Comment: There is a similar policy for iOS. I don't know any of the details; just hearsay.